# select inside <option > tag click function is not working

Tags: javascript

Select inside  tag click function is not working

```js
function TestsFunction() {

  var T = document.getElementById("TestsDiv"),
    displayValue = "";
  if (T.style.display == "")
    displayValue = "none";

  T.style.display = displayValue;
}

function TestsFunction1() {

  var T = document.getElementById("TestsDiv1"),
    displayValue = "";
  if (T.style.display == "")
    displayValue = "none";

  T.style.display = displayValue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <form>
      <div id="TestsDiv" style="display:none">
        <button id="btnclick">Copy</button>
      </div>
      <div id="TestsDiv1" style="display:none">
        <button id="btnclick1">dg</button>
      </div>

      <select>
        <option onclick="TestsFunction()" value="Please">Please select one</option>
        <option onclick="TestsFunction1()" value="Fruts">Fruts</option>

      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

in this case of sin Orio click function is working correctly

```
<option  onclick="TestsFunction()" value="Please">Please select one</option>
<option  onclick="TestsFunction1()" value="Fruts" >Fruts</option>
```

when I change it to this, its not working

```
<select>
   <option  onclick="TestsFunction()" value="Please">Vegitable</option>
   <option  onclick="TestsFunction1()" value="Fruits" >Fruits</option>  
</select>
```

Can any one give a solution for this problem please?

Comment: Use the `change` event of the `select` tag.

Comment: See the documentation: [`change` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: `option` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option does NOT support `onclick` attribute.  Use `onchange` handler on `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the function `TestsFunction1`, it was giving an unexpected end of input.
In order for this to work, you need to assign the `onchange` event listener to the `select` tag.

Here is a working snippet for you to try this out.

```js
function TestsFunction() {
         var T = document.getElementById("TestsDiv"),
         displayValue = "";
         
         if (T.style.display == "") {
            displayValue = "none";
            T.style.display = displayValue;
         }
 }
```

```html
<form>
      <div id="TestsDiv">
         <button id="btnclick" >Copy</button>
      </div>
      <div id="TestsDiv1">
         <button id="btnclick1">dg</button>
      </div>
      <select onchange="TestsFunction()" >
          <option value="F" >Fruts</option>                 
                            <option value="V" >Vegetable</option>   
           </select>     
    </form>
```

Comment: i should use select with<option> tag its not working

Comment: if there any posible

Comment: i want add in <select  onclick="TestsFunction(),TestsFunction0()"> but it's not working guide me please